# Can Access accdb files be used as a deployed back end?

Tags: ms-access, vb6

I recently was introduced to a program for maintaining "matters" for solicitors that used an MDB file as the back end. I found this surprising and even more surprising was the fact that the program could be used without a copy of Access installed on the machine (the program is 15 years old BTW).

It then got me to wondering. Can ACCDB files be used as back ends for deployed applications and following on from that, what would be the best front ends?

The point being here is that if someone were to create an application similar to the one above (not going to need even 1GB worth of storage space), create an installer package and distribute via CD or DVD what would be the best options for front and back ends?

I had to write (for university) a java program that used plain text files as the storage medium. Are text files commonly used? Or is there a standard deployed back end that I don't know about?

And as for front ends, surely one of the most pertinent points is what engine could be deployed with the application to run the front end bearing in mind this whole thing would need to be distributed together.

Comment: Yes, they can. The engine is free and the run time is free. You can use whatever you fancy. Here on SO, you will find java, vb,net and c#, amongst others.

Comment: IMHO the runtime would be too big a program to distribute as part of the application. And is it necessary if the ACCDB file is just a back end file?

Comment: No it is not, the note is additional information.

Comment: But is it common to use an ACCDB file as a back end for a deployed application? Or is there another more popular and better light weight back end out there?

Comment: And there you have it. This question will provoke too much debate, so it is unsuitable for SO. Yes it is common, yes there are other options. Are they better? That is a question of religion.

Comment: I don't agree with you at all. This is perfectly good question. Are what better? You haven't offered any alternatives to the ACCDB file. If I could get a couple it would give me something to go on.

Comment: Which technology type questions are not a good fit for Stackoverflow, you might like to check out http://stackoverflow.com/faq and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116821/deciding-which-technology-to-use-questions

Comment: There are two parts to your question: (1) "***Can*** ACCDB files be used as back ends for deployed applications?": Yes, they can; see the answer from MarkJ below. (2) "***Should*** ACCDB files be used as back ends for deployed applications?": That depends, and is too open-ended for the Stack Overflow Q+A format as @Remou pointed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was very common to use MDB files as the backing store for desktop programs. That's Microsoft decided to include the relevant runtime files (the "[Jet database engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Jet_Database_Engine)") into Windows, under the name "[Windows Data Access Components](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Data_Access_Components)". It is still present in Windows 8, although it is "functionally deprecated" which AFAIK means it will be maintained, but no new features will be added.

Microsoft [recommendations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810810.aspx):

> Use [Microsoft SQL Server Express Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/express.aspx) or [Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/compact.aspx) when developing new, non-Microsoft Access applications
>   requiring a relational data store...
>
> Applications can continue to use Jet with the intention of using
>   Microsoft Office 2003 and earlier files (.mdb and .xls) for
>   non-primary data storage. However, for these applications, you should
>   plan to migrate from Jet to the 2007 Office System Driver. You can
>   [download the 2007 Office System Driver](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=7554f536-8c28-4598-9b72-ef94e038c891), which allows you to read from
>   and write to pre-existing files in either Office 2003 (.mdb and .xls)
>   or the Office 2007 (*.accdb, *.xlsm, *.xlsx and *.xlsb) file formats.

**Important disclaimer**: there are **very many** ways of storing data: other relational database engines, "no SQL" databases, object serialisation etc. etc. It's meaningless to make any general statement about which is "better" without knowing about a specific project and the specific skills of the specific developers working on it.

Comment: But aren't SQL Server Express and compact too big to package?

Comment: I would not suggest SQL Server in any version for lightweight, hm? Where is SQLite, amongst others? The question is a shopping list http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158809/why-are-shopping-list-questions-bad

Comment: +1 for answering the central question "***Can*** ACCDB files be used as back ends for deployed applications", and for noting that the "2007 Office System Driver" is an additional component that must be installed. Jet (for .mdb files) is included in the base Windows install, but ACE (for .accdb files) is not.

Comment: @remou I deliberately didn't answer the "shopping list" question, see last paragraph of my answer.

Comment: Who knew that asking whether there was a better alternative to ACCDB files could be so taxing?

Answer (score -4):

I definitely do not recommend using ACCDB as backend. ACCDB as well as MDB files tend to crash without warning; e.g. when network connections break down or the client machine crashes. You then need to repair the database backend file probably suffering data loss.

I would rather recommend using a SQL Server database for this. For me MySQL often did the trick; it can also easily be backed up and is quite safe to use. MS SQL Server Express or compact (as mentioned above) are also very good choices.

Comment: This is simply not true. Anything that is not set up correctly will break. You will note that in the question the OP mentions an mdb in use for 15 years.

Comment: Well, I can only speak for what I encountered. And I have spent a lot of time repairing crashed mdb files (cannot be opened, needs to be repaired) that were used as backends.

Comment: As I said, anything used improperly will break. My experience over a great many years is the Access works very well for the small office.